# Can POST method contains both named parameters and POST body?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I am wondering if POST method can contain both named parameters and another POST body(which contains data).

I do not use multi-post method.

Comment: Are you saying you want to process two different posts on different php pages?

Comment: The body of a post request can contain arbitrary bytes.  By named parameters do you mean query parameters?

Comment: Can you please add more information, or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POST request can contain both querystring data (just like a GET) and a POST body.